# Adding request header to test_request_context in Flask unit test

Tags: python, unit-testing, flask, flask-restful

I have an Api based on Flask which receives an Access-Token in Header. This works fine.

In my code I check if the header is available, otherwise it's a 403 Forbidden access.

```
if 'Access-Token' in request.headers:
   token = request.headers['Access-Token']
else:
   return make_response('[HTTP_403_FORBIDDEN]', HttpStatusCode.HTTP_403_FORBIDDEN)
```

Now I'm writing an unit test and I'm stuck in the `request.headers`. I'm using `test_request_context()` but I cannot add any value to the headers as this is immutable.

I also tried this approach:

```
with app.test_request_context(environ_base={'Access-Token': token}):
```

which adds the header to `environ`, but not to the `request.headers`, here is where I'm a bit lost.

Other option would be to mock patch the request, but then I don't need the context.

So, how can I unit test `if 'Access-Token' in request.headers:` with `test_request_context`?

**EDIT:**

I found out how to set the header on this link:

https://gist.github.com/pgjones/0bd192d3fae7f6dfadead178dbac0e1e`

It basically seems to be a `werkzeug.http` convention for setting keys in environ dictionary:

If you want to add a header which key name is `Access-Token`, the environ_base key name must be named **HTTP_ACCESS_TOKEN**

That is how the code looks like now:

```py
with self.app.test_request_context(environ_base={'HTTP_ACCESS_TOKEN': token}):
```

Now the condition `if 'Access-Token' in request.headers:` works and returns **true**